# Using AMD Graphics card

Tags: ati, radeon

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my Lenovo Z51-70. It has both integrated Intel HD5500 graphics and AMD Radeon graphics card. But when I run the command "lshw -c video", its showing only Intel graphics. How can I switch to AMD graphics?

**EDIT**

Output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display' is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3824
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Radeon R9 M375
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have editted the question to include the info you have asked.

Comment: You can see AMD adapter.

Comment: @Anoop, You are contradicting yourself. You say it's showing only Intel, but the listing you provide shows both ...

Comment: @BogdanWilli yes. when I run lshw -c video, it showed intel graphics card. Anyways using below answer I was able to switch to Radeon and difference is visible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First install the latest fglrx driver if it is not installed.

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and reboot.

You can switch adapters in Catalyst Control Center or in terminal

```
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
```

switches to AMD

```
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu
```

switches to Intel

```
aticonfig --pxl
```

shows status.

Comment: this answer helped me a lot. i upvote 10 times if i could. thanks.