# Help for installing graphic card driver

Tags: drivers, ati

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04TLS in my Lenovo Z51-70 notebook. AMD Radeon™ AMD TROPO XT2 R9 M375 with 4GB GDDR3 dedicated, how can get driver for that graphic card
**NOTE**: No AMD Driver for that model

Comment: Does running the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` from the terminal show you an AMD graphics driver recommendation?

Comment: modalias : pci:v00001002d00006820sv000017AAsd00003824bc03sc80i00

vendor   : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]


model    : Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8800M Series]


driver   : xserver-xorg-video-ati - distro free builtin recommended


driver   : fglrx - distro non-free


driver   : fglrx-updates - distro non-free

Comment: There was a similar quesion here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/672823/using-amd-graphics-card Please let me know it that helped, as I am about to buy the same notebook and would like to know, if Ubuntu runs on it without problems.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` is not hard to understand. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
sudo reboot
```

After the computer reboots Ubuntu will be using the proprietary graphics driver that is compatible with your AMD Radeon TROPO XT2 R9 M375 graphics card.

This is the most up-to-date graphics driver for your graphics card that the default repositories of Ubuntu 14.04 have, but if you upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 at the end of April of this year, you will be able to install a more up-to-date graphics driver from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia:i386
```

and then this

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx*-
```

and then this

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: are you sure for nvidia ?!

Comment: Package nvidia:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nvidia:i386' has no installation candidate